# 4-20mA to adjustable set point relay

Tags: operational-amplifier

[![Why doesn't this work?

I can adjust pot and relay will energize. 4-20mA will not energize relay. [image: ][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJCrT.png)

Comment: What do you mean "4-20mA won't energize the relay"? At what level is it supposed to energize? Where is the pot set when the current source is supposed to energize the relay?

Comment: What doesn't what work?, be specific please.

Answer (score 0):

You need a load resistor for the 4-20mA. Perhaps 300 ohms 1%. And there is no reason to divide it by 2. Add a series resistor to control the hysteresis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkwfQ1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>